# ios POST elements not posting

Tags: php, objective-c, ios

Im trying to post some data to a php page and the posted elements arent going through. I know this because the php returns `$_REQUEST`, which is only the phpsession, not the username that should be posting. What isnt right here?

```
NSString *urlString = @"http://www.example.com/api";


NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];


[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"username\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"thisisit\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[request setHTTPBody:body];
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [body length]];

[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];



NSURLResponse *response = [[NSURLResponse alloc] init];
NSError *err;
NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&err];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the final boundary. Add this code just before `[request setHTTPBody:body]`

```
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```